# React-Router can't make subroutes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

Maybe somebody know why I can create subroutes
My code.

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={Main} >
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path="performance" component={Performance} />
        <Route path="home" component={Home} >
          <Route path="alert" component={Performance} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
</Provider>

// ...
// imports
import Main from './Main'
import Performance from './performance/PerformanceComponent'
import Home from './home/HomeComponent'

import {Router, Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
```

I can't go to this address -> /home/alert

And Have this errors in console

```
alert:11 GET http://0.0.0.0:3001/home/css/style.css 
alert:12 GET ...home/css/home.css 
alert:13 GET ...home/css/detailsView.css 
alert:26 GET ...home/bundle.tvc.js
```

I mean if I write wrong address I have special error

`Warning: [react-router] Location "/homealert" did not match any routes`

I don't have any idea how should I fix it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you saying that using /home/alert results in the `alert:11 GET http://0.0.0.0:3001/home/css/style.css...` errors in the console, but using /homealert results in the `Warning: [react-router] Location "/homealert" did not match any routes` error in the console?

Comment: yes. It's very strange

Answer (score 1):

You want this if you want to `Performance` component to render on `/home/alert`. You need to specify the complete path on each matching `Route`s.

```
  <Route path="/" component={Main} >
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="/performance" component={Performance} />
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} >
      <Route path="/home/alert" component={Performance} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
```

Nesting routes applies to components, not paths. Your app will render as below for `/home/alert`:

```
<Main>
  <Home>
    <Performance>
```